# VB6.0 SMS Message box

Tags: vb6, sms

Hi guys i have this problem.

The problem is that i dont know how to make a message box whether the message is sent or failed.
how am i going to code it i totaly have no idea.
i cant search it on google. i hope you could help me out
im using GSM Modem.below is my sending code.

```
MSComm1.Output = "AT" & vbCrLf
Sleep 100
MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf
Sleep 200
MSComm1.Output = "AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & MobileNum & Chr(34) & vbCrLf
MSComm1.Output = TMPMESEJ & Chr(26)
List1.AddItem MSComm1.Input
Sleep 300
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: i want to make a message that displays the status send or failed sir

Comment: MsgBox.... http://vb6reference.tomswebdesign.net/msgbox.html

Comment: sorry sir but i already know how to use a message box, what i want is that how can i know that the message i sent is failed or successfully sent? i want to display it via message box or display it on the list box. i hope its clear.

Comment: what is the data you expect after a failed command, and what is the data you expect after a successfull command?

Comment: if the message is failed i want a something that will tell to the user that the message is failed or something like a message box or a label, same as the sent message. i have a list box that list all the input from mscomm but it always says OK although the GSM modem has no load at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the logic in OnComm Event of MSCOMM control.

The OnComm event is generated whenever the value of the CommEvent property of MSCOMM control changes, indicating that either a communication event or an error occurred.

You need to write a Select Case statement on MSComm.CommEvent and analyse the outcome.

Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194922

Comment: i have tried the code sir but still it no luck and i don't know how to make it. i have tried the mscomm input and put the input to the list box and it always says ok even though the number i put is a different network supposedly it will give some other input

Comment: you always get "OK" because the command you are sending is ok, but the data inside it doesn't work so you probably need to do a check after that to test if you can reach that other network, and use the answer of that check to show your messagebox

Comment: @Hrqls how am i going to do that sir?

Comment: @DenverBomb : there is probably some buffer you can read out, or some status command which shows if the messsage is still being sent, or if the send it complete ... have a look at the AT commands your modem supports